# Why is the user not set here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb

I`m having problems understanding why I'm not able to set the user in the app. Register and login work.
Upon refreshing the app the user is lost, but the access token is still there. Also when I try to create a product, the manufacturer(owner) of it is undefined and not listed in the DB.
I've been debugging it and I can see that req.user is not found by the app and stays undefined/null.

I`m attaching the whole github project for easier code check, if someone decides to help me out here.
https://github.com/theBoomstick7/projectOils2

Thanks in advance everyone!

Changed all possible setting of the user, register and logout and login do work, but not the intended way.

I understand the design is not good, will be fixed later

As I understand this is not a good way to ask a question here, let me add some parts of the code.

This is the server controller of the product:

```js
const {getAll,createProduct} = require(`../services/productService`)

const productController = require(`express`).Router()

productController.post(`/create`, async(req,res) => {
    const data = req.body
    console.log(req.user)
    try {
        const userId = req?.user?._id
        const product = await createProduct(data,userId)
        res.status(201).json(product)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({error:error.message})
    }

    res.end()
})
```

This is the angular auth service :

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { tap } from 'rxjs';
import { IUser } from '../interfaces/user';


const AUTH_API_URL = 'http://localhost:3000' // Change this to environment directory later


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  user: null | IUser | undefined
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  get isLogged(): boolean {
    if(this.user){
      return true
    }else 
    {
      return false
    }
  }   

  register(data: {}){
    return this.http.post<IUser>(`${AUTH_API_URL}/register`,data).pipe(
      tap((user) => {
        this.user = user
        localStorage.setItem(`accessToken`, this.user.accessToken)
      })
    )
  }
  login(data: {}){
    return this.http.post<IUser>(`${AUTH_API_URL}/login`, data). pipe(
      tap((user) => {
        this.user = user
        localStorage.setItem(`accessToken`, this.user.accessToken)
      })
    )
  }
  logout(){
    this.user = null
    return localStorage.removeItem(`accessToken`)
  }

}
```

This is the way the user register is handled :

```js
export class RegisterComponent {
  
  errors: any;
  
 
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private userService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}
  
  registerForm = this.fb.group({
    email: [``,[Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    username: [``, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
    password: [``, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
    rePass: [``, [Validators.required,passwordValidator]]
  })


  register(): void{
    this.userService.register(this.registerForm.value).subscribe
      ({

        next: () => this.router.navigate([`/`]),
        error:(err)=>   {
          this.errors = err.error?.error
        }

      })
  
    this.registerForm.reset()
    
  }    
}
```

This is how a product is created
Product Angular service :

```js
export class ProductsService {

 
  constructor(private http : HttpClient, private router : Router) { }

  createProduct(data : {}){
    return this.http.post<IProduct>(`${API_URL}/create`, data)
  }
}
```

Create product form :

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Route, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductsService } from '../products.service'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-product',
  templateUrl: './create-product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-product.component.css']
})
export class CreateProductComponent {

  errors: string | undefined = undefined;
  constructor(private fb : FormBuilder, private productService: ProductsService, private router : Router){}

  createProductForm = this.fb.group({
    title : [``, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(12)]],
    imageUrl: [``, [ Validators.required]],
    description: [``, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]]
  })

  createProduct(){
    this.productService.createProduct(this.createProductForm.value).subscribe({
      next: () => this.router.navigate([`/products`]),
      error: (err) => {
        this.errors = err.error?.error
      }
    })
   
    
    
    this.createProductForm.reset()
  }
}
```

I hope this makes it easier to everyone.

PP, this is my app interceptor :

```js
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable, Provider } from "@angular/core";
import { mergeMap, Observable, tap } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class AppInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{
    accessToken:any | [] | null = localStorage.getItem(`accessToken`)

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> 
    {
       if(this.accessToken)
       {
        return next.handle(req.clone({ setHeaders: {'X-Authorization' : this.accessToken}}))
    }
        else 
        {
            return next.handle(req.clone())
        }
    }
    }

    export const AppInterceptorProvider: Provider = {
        provide:HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: AppInterceptor,
        multi:true
    }
```

Comment: Please do not ask us to debug remote code in a repo. Instead edit the question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Last time people asked for the whole github, so they can debug it themself. I will add more now if this is not okay, please excuse me

Comment: I`ve updated, hopefully makes more sense now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood well your question. If not, let me know. I will edit my answer.

I could debug your App.

You save your `accessToken` in the local storage, but not the User object. When you refresh the browser, the "accessToken" is there, but the user not because it was removed from the browser's memory.

In this case, your server knows that you are logged in, but your app (frontend) not.

In the `auth.service.ts` you have to save the user:

```
localStorage.setItem(`user`,  JSON.stringify(this.user));
```

In the `app.component.ts` you have to load the user again and set it into the `userService` instance:

```
  const myUser: string= localStorage.getItem('user') + '';
  const loadedUser: IUser = JSON.parse(myUser);
  console.log('Loaded User: ' + loadedUser)
  this.userService.setLoggedUser(loadedUser);
```

An alternative solution could be check in the `app.component.ts`the presence of the `accessToken`. If it is there, you can call a new REST method on the server to get the logged user for that token.

Comment: I understand what my mistake is and what you are proposing as a solution. However, upon trying to implement it typescript goes mad and I have 9 errors on all this lol. I`ve created a separate method for the setLoggedUser : setLoggedUser(){
    return localStorage.setItem(`user`,  JSON.stringify(this.user));
  }  and after this it goes mad in the app.component. Appreciate the time taken to help me out on this here!

Comment: @TheBoomstick7 you are welcome. Please, mark this answer as the solution, if it helped to find mistakes, improve your code and think on new solutions. For sure, you have to code a little bit to fix or improve the code.

Comment: Your answer helped me improve definetely. However the issue still persists... I`ve added this in the app.component.ts : ` if(localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) {
        this.userService.getUserData().subscribe() 
       }`                                                                                                                               
 The getUserData method is this : ` getUserData()
  {
    return this.http.get<IUser>(`${AUTH_API_URL}/userData`).pipe(
      tap((user) => {
        if(user){
          this.user = user
        }
      })
    )
  }`

Comment: This is on the server controller for the route : `authController.get(`/userData`, (req,res) => {
    const user = req.user
    
    if(user)
    {
    res.status(200).json(user) 
    }
     
})`  I`m getting lost here why it is not working still. I went for the 2nd solution to add a new REST method

Comment: Ok, I`ve fixed this by adding a middleware in the server which handles the req.user: const authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    const accessToken = req.headers['x-authorization'];
    if(accessToken){
        try {
            const user = validateToken(accessToken);
            req.user = {
                'email': user.email,
                'username': user.username,
                '_id': user._id,
                accessToken
            }
        } catch (error) {
            res.json(error)
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    next();
}

Comment: Great! You needed only a small push to walk again with your own legs :-)

Comment: To be honest, I`ve used someone else`s code to help me. I don`t think it is a big problem, it wasn`t simply copy-paste, I accept it as part of the learning curve reading and implementing someone else`s code.

Comment: No problem. It is part of the game. Copying, pasting, adjusting ... Sucess on your project !